# Segmentation fault in opencv usage

Tags: segmentation-fault, fopen

Running on Ubuntu 12.04

The following program first reads 50 characters from a file, and then converts these values into int. 
Actually the values in the file are like these:

> 0020.50 0020.49 0020.47 0020.46 0020.51 0020.50 0020.50 0020.49 0020.49 0020.50 0020.50 0020.52 0020.51 0020.47 0020.49 0020.48 0020.48 0020.50 0020.49 0020.49 0020.48 0020.50 0020.48 0020.50 0020.51 0020.47 0020.47 0020.47 0020.49 0020.50 0020.47 0020.53 0020.42 0020.57 0020.43 0020.47 0020.49 0020.50 0020.46 0020.49 0020.40 0020.48 0020.32 0020.39 0020.55 0021.39 0020.66 0020.77 0020.34 0019.52 0052 24.81

I am simply opening a file and then closing it, But I have some openCV specific header files included:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    FILE *fp;
    int i,x;
    int read;

    char * buffer; 

buffer =(char *)malloc(100); 

    fp=fopen("Xvalues.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL)
        {
        printf("File opening failed");
        }

printf("File opened successfully");



    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    }
```

But it always gives segmentation fault.

The way I am compiling this file is:

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

And I have a cmake file (**cMakeLists**)with the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.9)

project(demo)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_definition("-g2") 
add_executable(new1 new1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(new1 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and then compile using cmake as

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

I get segmentation fault.

**Here is the output of gdb with core**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ravi/Desktop/New/build# gdb new1 core
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/ravi/Desktop/New/build/new1...done.
[New LWP 4105]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./new1'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb757a2f2 in fclose () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb757a2f2 in fclose () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x08048800 in main () at /home/ravi/Desktop/New/new1.cpp:35
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x08048800 in main () at /home/ravi/Desktop/New/new1.cpp:35
35  fclose(fp);
(gdb)print fp 
$1= (FILE *) 0x0
```

From this I can see some thing is wrong with the way I am opening the file. But what is wrong here  ?

**Solved**

Chris was right.  when I added \n, it is printing  "File opening failed".  I saw the directory where Xvalues.txt lies is different than my binary.

Comment: in your CMakeLists.txt: add_definitions("-g2")

Comment: apart from the horribly formatting and c-style file-reading, if one of your points has 5224.81 as coord, this will overflow a 800x800 image.

Comment: your code works for me without segmentation fault.

Comment: @berak  But I am only plotting first 50 points. Also can you tell me what is the alternate to this C-style file reading ?

Comment: @ChrisMaes Ok. I will add it at the end. right?

Comment: @user3891236 I'm not sure about the order in CMakeLists.txt; I put it before the "add_executable" line for sure.

Comment: @ChrisMaes That worked, I  am able to get dgb running with core dump. It is generating coredump at read=fread(buffer,1,50,fp);. What is wrong here ?

Comment: I don't see the mistake immediately. Please try to pinpoint the problem yourself: try reading 1 character for starters; print out that character (don't forget your newline when printing),...

Comment: maybe your file didn't open correctly but you didn't see the message: you won't see your error message because you should add a newline: printf("File opening failed\n");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67093/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-user3891236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat; there were two problems:

1. no newline when printing an error
2. the file pointer is NULL

**newline**

when printing something you need to put a newline at the end (or use fflush). Otherwise it won't show.

```
printf("File opening failed");
```

**file pointer is NULL**

probably your program does not find the file you want to read from OR you have the wrong permissions.